# How to customize Actionbar.Tab?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm using an actionbar with NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS set. What do you call that rectangle that appears at the bottom of the tab that is selected? And how do I customize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how it is called, maybe *tab highlight*.

Anyway, customize it with the [Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator).

Comment: Wow. Thanks for answering! I already found that tool BUT I have no idea how to use the files it produces. Maybe you could teach me?

Comment: Download the ZIP file and copy all the files into your project's `res` folder. Then you have to set the theme that was generated in the `styles.xml` file as `android:theme` in your project's `AndroidManifest.xml`.